# Containerize C# Winforms Applications

Tags: c#, winforms, docker

I have a stand-alone Winform application. it is possible to containerize it in docker. Does docker support UI based application? Do I need docker for the purpose of testing the application?

Comment: https://forums.docker.com/t/windows-forms-applications-in-container/22306

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You will be able to Containerize it using https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework-runtime. UI-based application is running on top of the .Net framework, so it is fully supported. However, will you able to interact with the UI is a different question. You can interact via command line or network but not UI.

For testing, if you just test how the application works, you probably don't need Docker, but if you want to test the containerization then you will need Docker for Desktop.

Comment: Are you sure? Can we run the windows form application in the docker containers? I couldn't find any documentation related to this. Can you share the documentation if possible

Comment: I feel this answer is misleading. Sure, you might be able to create the Docker Image, and sure you might be able to start the application process, but the entire point of a WinForms application is the UI.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't successfully containerize a Winforms application that requires a GUI, because "containers don't support Graphic User Interface (GUI)" - at least at the time of writing this reply (July 2023).

"Containers aren't a solution equivalent to desktop application virtualization. They support only server-side applications that don't require an interactive session. Because they run on specialized container images, they support only those applications that don't need a graphical front end."

Reference:
[What can't be moved to Windows Containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/lift-shift-to-containers)