# Running WinForms Apps in DotNet Framework Container

Tags: c#, windows, docker, winforms

Is it at all possible to run apps that use winforms in Windows docker containers? All of our software heavily relies on winforms, however it is possible to run all of these tools without interacting with the GUI. I attempted to debug the launcher from inside the container and I noticed the application stopped at the `Run` function for the `WindowsFormsApplicationBase` base class.

```cs
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices;

namespace Program
{
   static class Program
   {
      [STAThread]
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         Application.EnableVisualStyles();
         Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

         MyApp myApp = new MyApp();
         myApp.Run(args);
      }
   }

   class MyApp : WindowsFormsApplicationBase
}
```

Call Stack

```
[Managed to Native Transition]  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(System.IntPtr dwComponentID, int reason, int pvLoopData)  Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context)    Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) Unknown
Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll!Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun() Unknown
Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll!Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()    Unknown
Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll!Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(string[] commandLine)   Unknown
MyApp.exe!MyApp.Program.Main(string[] args) Line 49 C#
```

Comment: What do you mean WinForms isn't actually needed? Do you actually need Win Forms or not?

Comment: It is built using WinForms but I do not actually need to interact with the GUI. I cannot modify any of these tools either as they are out of my control.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57750630/containerize-c-sharp-winforms-applications) answer your question?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Saw that earlier this week however I am already using a dotnet/framework/runtime based image. I am launching everything via command line and still getting the hang up.

Comment: GUI is not supported on Windows containers. If the app has a dependency on the desktop on the server side (where you run either on a container or a VM or physical host), then it won't work on Windows containers. If the app has a server component that does not require a GUI and users have the UI on their own machines that connects to the serve-side, then this would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Winforms do work in the `dotnet/framework/sdk` image. This was tested by creating a simple winforms app that created an empty text file on form showing and form closing since Windows Applications can't use `Console.WriteLine()`.

```cs
namespace TestGUI_DockerApp
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      private int i = 0;

      private void ExitTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         i++;

         if (i > 4)
         {
            Close();
         }
      }

      protected override void OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e)
      {
         DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;

         string filename = $".\\{dateTime:yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss_fff}.txt";
         File.Create($".\\{filename}");

         base.OnFormClosed(e);
      }

      private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         exitTimer.Enabled = true;

         DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;

         string filename = $".\\{dateTime:yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss_fff}.txt";
         File.Create($".\\{filename}");
      }
   }
}
```

I saw two different text files being created and the process closed shortly after that.

The error I was seeing in my original post was due to an unhandled exception being thrown somewhere else in the code. Since it was unhadled, the program was waiting for me to acknowledge it before closing. Since I couldn't acknowledge it, it appeared to be hanging.