# Docker and Windows Forms

Tags: c#, docker

Good morning,

I wanted to know if it was possible to put Windows Forms in a Docker container. And if so, how is this possible? For the moment, I cannot find any documentation of this type. Either an incomplete disconfirmation

Comment: [Containerize C# Winforms Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57750630/containerize-c-sharp-winforms-applications)

Comment: Why do you want this? What problem do you expect it to solve? I suspect what you're looking for is [AppContainers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/msix-container) not Docker